How do I stop R changing a table with one row into a vector
This happens inside a program, but here is a simple example of what happens
x = table(rep(1,10), 1:10)
dim(x)
class(x)
y = x[, order(dimnames(x)[[2]])]
class(y)
dim(y)

y has become a vector, but I want to stay with a table.

I re-structured your question and changed the code slightly. Based on the example given, I do not understand what you try to achieve with order(). However, you might want to wrap in as.table(), i.e. as.table(y)?

Take a look at ?drop. Applied it may look like table[,1, drop=F]

Also, a tibble doesn't drop by default, e.g. library(tibble); as_tibble(matrix(rep(1:3, 2), ncol=2))[,1]

Thanks so much Andre. Your first answer worked, but the second didn't
